# How to trigger sheet on TabView click

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I show a sheet when I click a tab in TabView? All the examples on the internet use a Button to trigger an update but I want to make the sheet appear when a user clicks one of the tabs in TabView.

I tried changing the boolean state variable in a tabbed view by adding .onAppear(), but it doesn't seem to work.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        return TabView {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house")
                }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$showSheet) {
            SheetView(isShown: self.$showSheet)
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, I basically want SheetView to show up when I click the tab. I don't want to replace HomeView with SheetView since I want it to be a sheet instead of static view. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved, albeit rather hackishly, by moving your State variables up one level and controlling the flow within a `Group`. Here, I just moved them to the app state for simplicity.

```
final class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var shouldShowActionSheet: Bool = true
    @Published var selectedContentViewTab: ContentViewTabs = .none
}
```

In `SceneDelegate.swift`:

```
 . . . 
 window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView.environmentObject(AppState()))
 . . .
```

And finally in your view:

```
public enum ContentViewTabs: Hashable {
    case none 
    case home
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

    var body: some View {

        Group {

            if (appState.selectedContentViewTab == .home && self.appState.shouldShowActionSheet) {
                Text("").sheet(isPresented: self.$appState.shouldShowActionSheet, onDismiss: {
                    self.appState.shouldShowActionSheet.toggle()
                    self.appState.selectedContentViewTab = .none
                }, content: {
                    Text("Oll Korrect, Chaps!")
                })
            } else {

                TabView(selection: self.$appState.selectedContentViewTab) {
                    Text("First View")
                        .font(.title)
                        .tabItem {
                            VStack {
                                Image("first")
                                Text("First")
                            }
                    }.tag(ContentViewTabs.home)


                }
            }

        }

    }
 }
```